# How to quantify a parent's influence of a node in a Bayesian Network?

Tags: predictor, graphical-model, bayesian-network

Consider a toy bayesian network that models purchase of items at a store. The nodes include: *{Brand, Price, Purchased}*.

[image]

- It is possible that when you marginalize over price, P(purchase|brand) may indicate some brands are purchased more often than others.
- However, it's also possible that some brands are cheaper than others, and that P(purchase) is more strongly influenced by price than by brand.

**Questions:**

1. **Is there an established method to assess the influence of the parents in this diagram?**

   - In other words, is there a way to assess whether or not it is price that influences purchases more than brand?
2. Is this method robust to adding additional nodes?

   - My understanding is some approaches (i.e. logistic regression) run into is as additional nodes are added, the coefficients for each covariate can change significantly

Comment: I noticed one tool, `bnlearn` has a function called ["arc strength"](http://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/arc.strength.html). It looks like this uses bootstrapping to perform structure learning. In my question, I'm interested in knowing if there is a disciplined method to identifying influence using some combination of fundamentals, i.e.: conditioning, marginalization, querying, ratio-tests, etc.

Comment: I vaguely recall it's doable. My math-fu is failing me right now though; you may reach the answer yourself before me. A hack that might work is to replace the p(Purchase|Brand) vertex with a new conditional dependency on a 'pseudoBrand' node in the middle such that p(pseudoBrand && Brand)=1, for a `o<8>o`-shaped graph.

Comment: @jkm thank you for the reply. Would you be able to elaborate a bit more on how the pseudoBrand node helps with the questions above?

Comment: Just a visualization hack. It gives you two independent nodes with a common cause going into the Purchase node. You can then decompose: `p(Pur|Pri,pBrand,Brand) = p(Pur|Pri)p(Pri|Brand)p(Brand) + p(Pur|pBrand)p(pBrand|Brand)p(Brand)`, meaning that if you aggregated on price, all variance in the likelihood of purchase would be explained by the influence of the brand and vice versa.